# orientdb stop traverse with some condition

Tags: orientdb

Given this graph:
[image]
A third party may or not own a parameter.

A Parameter is represented by a *context*, *code* and *value* (EX: `CREATE VERTEX Parameter SET context='val1', code='val2', value='val3'`).
A ThirdParty is represented by a type (Ex: `CREATE VERTEX ThirdParty SET type=7`)

Starting from vertex #40:0, i would like to retrieve the value of a given parameter(example, parameter with context='val1' and code='val2') attached to this node (a node can have different parameters). If the node doesn't own the given parameter, then i would like to traverse the parents of this node one by one till i find a value for the given parameter.

I tried using this query:

```
SELECT parameter.value FROM (MATCH {class:ThirdParty, 
          where: (type = 7)}.in('parent_of')
          {while: (out('owns').size() == 0), 
          where: (out('owns').size() > 0)}.out('owns')
          {as: parameter} RETURN parameter)
```

but the problem is, a ThirdPary can have multiple Parameters, with different *context* and *code*, and i can't find how to modify the **while** part in the query to compare with the given parameter (context='val1' and code='val2').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be this one:

```
 SELECT parameter.value FROM (
   MATCH 
      {class:ThirdParty, where: (type = 7)}
      .in('parent_of')
      {
        while: (
           not (
             out('owns').context contains "val1"
             AND
             out('owns').code contains "val2"
           )
        ), 
        where: (
          out('owns').context contains "val1"
          AND
          out('owns').code contains "val2"
        )
      }.out('owns')
      {as: parameter, where:(code = "val2" and context = "val1")} 
   RETURN parameter
 )
```

BUT

1. you cannot use "context" as a property name, because it refers to the query context and you won't have the result you expect
2. I found a bug on 2.2.19 that breaks this query, I just fixed it and pushed the fix on 2.2.x branch. The fix will be released with 2.2.20. In the meantime, in a few hours you'll find the snapshot here https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-community/2.2.20-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks Luigi for your answer! The bug you fixed concerns the error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Implement SuffixIdentifier!`? Because when i execute the query by removing the part `out('owns').context contains "val1" AND` from the `while` and `where` clauses, i am getting the `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: I just made a test using the snapshot and it is working very good! I just had to add `where: (code="val2")` to the `{as: parameter}` clause, to retrieve the value of the given parameter, otherwise the query is returning the values of all parameters attached to the node. Thank you for your help! i started working on orientdb only yesterday and i am already a big fan! :)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the clarification, I'm updating the original answer