# Stop traversing after edge (orientdb)

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

How to stop traversing after edge class?

The graph for the query `TRAVERSE bothE(), bothV() FROM ( SELECT FROM Title WHERE title_id IN [12] )` looks like this:

[image: Relation graph example]

If I wrote (for blue graph):

```
TRAVERSE bothE("E14", "E5", "E6"), bothV() FROM ( SELECT FROM Title WHERE title_id IN [12] )
```

it don't gave me `V 970`.

How to construct a query that will return the part I need? I would like the whole graph to be returned if there exists an orange route.

I tested: `TRAVERSE inE(..), outE(...), bothE()` and `WHILE $parent.$current.@class != "E13"` bit it don't works.

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/43776591/1194525, but if I understand correctly, MATCH can be used at a well known well.

Comment: Hi, what's the expected result? Thx

Comment: could you attach a db export for testing?

Comment: DB export: https://app.box.com/s/m624p6nf04njj2vjsxtwn3h268ugm864 
Expected result: blue, without red and orange. (One piece group + Dragon Ball Z, without other Dragon Ball's). `E13` - is `Character` relation

Comment: How about `SELECT expand(both()) FROM Title WHERE title_id IN [12]` ?

Comment: In this case yes, but generally NO. (And it don't gave me Edges) Your query equivalent to `TRAVERSE bothE(), bothV() FROM ( SELECT FROM Title WHERE title_id IN [12] ) WHILE $depth <=2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea how to do it in 2 queries, but could use improvement, eg .: Doing this in 1 query.

step 1: Traverse graph by all "right" edges.

```
TRAVERSE bothE("Prequel", "Sequel"), bothV() FROM (
  SELECT FROM Title WHERE title_id IN [12] )
```

step 2: Get all Vertex `rid` from response (in client)

step 3: Query by "stop" edges for all  Vertex `rid` from previous query.

```
TRAVERSE bothE("Character"), bothV() FROM (
  SELECT FROM Title WHERE title_id IN [12, 431, 432, 433, ...] )
  MAXDEPTH 2
```

step 4: Merge responses (Vertex + Edges) in client.